# How can I force windows 10 to behave like I always have my monitor plugged in?

Tags: windows, display, steam-link

How can I force windows 10 to behave like I always have my monitor plugged in? It's because I want to be able to play with steam link without needing my monitor turned on.

Comment: I bet your display uses either display port or DV-I. If you have VGA (SUB-D) or HDMI, that should not uninstall your monitor if its turned off. Unplugged is something you cannot overrule though. It needs to be plugged in.

Comment: @LPChip Display port, also, sorry for confusing you I realize I should've wrote turned on. That being said, any way with it plugged in but not turned on?

Comment: If your monitor is plugged in and used, it will turn on (always for all the computers I see). I unplugged mine for 3 weeks recently, went across the ocean and used my home computer with ease. No issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because Display Port monitors are uninstalled when you turn off the display, and reinstalled when you turn the monitor on.

There are a few possible solutions that will work.

1. If your monitor has a power saving feature, disable it. On some monitors this actually stops the entire uninstall process and the monitor is remembered by windows even when turned off.
2. Don't use Display Port. The blue VGA connector (Sub-D) will definitely work, DVI will only work if you use the analog version (DVI-I), not the digital one (DVI-D). HDMI will also work. When the monitor is connected by the proper connection, it will not get uninstalled when powered off.